# UIScrollView setContentInset causes scroll skip in ios8

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8

I'm having a problem when creating a pull to refresh mechanism at the bottom of a scrollview. The code works perfectly smoothly in iOS7, but in iOS8 the scrollview instantly skips up before then animating to the correct position.

I'm tracking the scroll until it has rubber-banded beyond kPullToRefreshHeightPX (in my case this is 40px), and setting a flag to then inset on release, and trigger a content refresh.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (_webShouldInsetScrollView == NO && (scrollView.contentOffset.y > ((scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) + kPullToRefreshHeightPX)))
    {
        _webShouldInsetScrollView = YES;
    }
}
```

If on end dragging we have dragged beyond our refresh distance, then we inset (and run our little refresh animation) and show the next results page.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (_webShouldInsetScrollView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, kPullToRefreshHeightPX, 0.0f)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

        [self performSelector:@selector(showNextResultsPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
    }
}
```

I've read other issues with UIScrollViews in iOS8, one of which talked about `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` being set to false in iOS7, but now true by default in iOS8, but this has no effect on the above code. Has anyone else had a similar experience and figured a way round it?

Comment: I'm seeing exactly same thing. Didn't figure out yet the solution though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fix that issue,:D

```
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0, 0, 0)];
scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
```

Answer (score 1):

We have exactly the same issue...

After digging deeper I have seen, that somehow initially the target inset is set somewhere:

let's say I pull down the tableView from 200 to 500 - on `scrollViewDidEndDragging` I trigger the animation like this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         scrollView.contentInset = targetInset;
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Instead of animating smoothly from 500 back to -let's say- 250, the targetValue (250) is set once before  the correct animated values are set...

My Workaround has been to set a animation-flag before starting the animation. I reset it in the complete-block... The scroller checks this flag and sets the targetValue only if the animation is over:

```
_isAnimatingInset = YES;
_currentTopInsetTarget = targetInset.top;

 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         scrollView.contentInset = targetInset;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //Workaround for a iOS8-Bug see property-comment for further infos
                         _isAnimatingInset = NO;
                         scrollView.contentInset = targetInset;
                     }];

    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This minimizes the effect, but unfortunately at this moment I cannot prevent the setting of this wrong value (instead I reset it to the previous what also leads to a small hickUp in the animation...)

Answer (score 0):

After searching for quite some time I can not find the suitable answer. And looking by several pull-to-refersh implementation from the github (running them in iOS8 simulator) I can see that all of them shows exactly same jumping on iOS8.

Here is what I was able to do to minimize that effect. To recap the problem: when our refresh control needs to stay visible we're trying to adjust `contentInset` by the value of our control height in the superview `scrollView`. Changing the contentInset triggers scrolling content (on both iOS7 and iOS8), and on iOS8 this jump is quite visible.

I removed any changes in contentInset from basically `startRefresh` function of custom pull-to-refres. In your case - remove whole `UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations` from `scrollViewDidEndDragging`.

And add something like that into `scrollViewDidScroll` handler (beginning of it):

```
if (self.isRefreshing) {
    // If we already scrolled back past the point of our control height and we haven't changed
    // contentInset yet - update it

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > -CONTROL_HEIGHT && scrollView.contentInset.top == 0) {
        UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
        inset.top = CONTROL_HEIGHT;
        scrollView.contentInset = inset;
    }
    return;
}

...
```